# Were the golden bells intended for Aaron or the people in Exodus 28:33-35?

Tags: exodus, law, moses

Exodus 34 NASB

> 33 You shall make on its hem pomegranates of blue and purple and scarlet material, all around on its hem, and ***bells of gold*** between them all around: 34 a golden bell and a pomegranate, ***a golden bell*** and a pomegranate, all around on the hem of the robe. 35 It shall be on Aaron [v]when he ministers; and [w]its tinkling shall be heard when he enters and [x]leaves the holy place before the Lord, ***so that he will not die***

Were the golden bells intended for Aaron or the people?.

Answer (score 1):

Verse 35 says specifically that the bell would be upon Aaron so that the people could hear him moving around in the temple. This was so that the people outside could know if Aaron was struck dead before the Lord, since the bell would not ring for a long long time if that were the case.

Comment: Exodus 28:35 says the bells are to prevent his death, not to indicate his death. This is more enigmatic than the usual parroted answer. It seems it is to alert the LORD of his entrance.